# Problema alretornar valor en template con Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

soy muuuy novato tanto en Python como en django y como tal me he quedado atascado.
Tengo el siguiente código en view:

```
def incidencias(request)
  mb = MailBox(host).login(user , password)
  messages = mb.fetch(AND(subject = "[condición de busqueda"], seen = True)
    mark_seen=False
    bulk=False
  for msg in messages:
    #esto lo hago para comprobar la salida por terminal y es correcto
     print(msg.from_, ':', msg.subject)
  context = {'files' : msg.text, 'sub' : msg.subject, 'encabe' : msg.from_}
  return render(request, 'incidencias/index.html', context)
```

Y en el Template de html imprimo:

```
<p>{{encabe}}</p>
<p>{{sub}}</p>
<p>{{files}}</p>
```

El problema que tengo es que, la salida por terminal me imprime todos los mensajes con la condición pero, al pasarlo al template solo me imprime el último mensaje, no todos.
¿donde me equivoco?.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si mueves el print a fuera del ciclo `for` verás que también te pasa lo mismo, solo pon tu  variable `context` dentro del `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera para obtener todos los mensajes:

```
def incidencias(request)
    mb = MailBox(host).login(user , password)
    messages = mb.fetch(AND(subject = "[condición de busqueda"], seen = True)
    mark_seen=False
    bulk=False

    # pasar todos lo mensajes al template en 'messages'
    return render(request, 'incidencias/index.html', {'messages' : messages})
```

y en el template verificas la existencia de los mensajes, en caso de existir entonces haces un ciclo para mostrar cada uno de los mensajes:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for msg in messages %}
        <p>{{msg.encabe}}</p>
        <p>{{msg.sub}}</p>
        <p>{{msg.files}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: puedes añadir una descripción mas amplia de que hace tu código? gracias.

Comment: te agregue unos cuantos comentarios mas, realmente no hay mucho que explicar, espero te sean de ayuda

Comment: te sugiero que los comentarios los documentes fuera del código y no dentro del código, incluso lo que acabas de hacer hace ilegible tu ejemplo del témplate en el Sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias @KevinRamirezZavalza, lo probaré y te comento.

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza te debo unas cuantas cervezas (si eres mayor de edad)...¡Funciona!, gracias.